# What is the probability that a committee of $4$ people chosen from $5$ married couples does not contain a husband and wife?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

"A committee of four is chosen at random from 5 married couples. The chance that the committee will not include a husband and his wife is

$A. 8/21$

$B. 6/17$

$C. 9/17$

$D. 5/21$"

How to do$?$

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your own attempt at the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: I draw a tree diagram but found that by counting is very tedious. Then I get stuck and unable to proceed.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the denominator?

Comment: Is that 10 X 9 X 8 X 7?

Comment: That is correct.  Can you guess the numerator?

Comment: Then I don't know :-(

Answer (score 2):

As you determined, the number of ways of selecting four of the ten people in order is $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$.

Let's select a committee that does not contain a married couple.  We have $10$ ways to pick the first person. That leaves nine people, one of whom is the spouse of the first person selected for the committee, leaving us with eight choices for the second person.  Of the eight remaining people, two have spouses on the committee, leaving six choices for the third person.  By similar reasoning, there are four ways to select the fourth member of the committee.  Hence, the probability that no two of the four members of the committee are married is 
$$P = \frac{10 \cdot 8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}$$

**Alternate Solution:**  The number of ways we can select a committee is the number of ways we can select a subset of four of the ten people, which is $$\binom{10}{4}$$
where
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
To select a committee that does not contain a husband and wife, we must select one person from each of four of the five couples.  We can select the four of the five couples in $\binom{5}{4}$ ways.  From each of the four selected couples, we can select one of the two people in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways.  Hence, the probability that a committee of four people is selected that does not contain a husband and wife is 
$$\frac{\binom{5}{4}\binom{2}{1}^4}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

Comment: I didn't think of it that way, but I suppose you could line up the five couples, select four of them, then select one member of each selected couple.  In this case, the denominator would be the number of ways of selecting a subset (an unordered selection) of $4$ of the $10$ people.

Comment: Thanks again!!!!
Can I ask one question further: can the above be represented by nPr or nCr?

Comment: The denominator in the first solution can be represented as $$P(10, 4) = \frac{10!}{(10 - 4)!} = \frac{10!}{6!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6!}{6!} = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$$  I do not see a good way of expressing the numerator in the form $P(n, r)$, although it is an ordered selection.  In the second solution, I used combinations in both the numerator and denominator.  $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} = C(n, k)$$

Comment: Truly thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using inclusion-exclusion.**  For a more direct approach, see @N.F.Taussig's answer.

Let our sample space be the number of ways of picking four people from these ten where order doesn't matter.  There are $\binom{10}{4}=210$ number of ways to do this.

Let $A_1$ denote the event that the first husband-wife pair is picked simultaneously when picking a committee of four people.  Similarly, let $A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5$ denote the events that other husband-wife pairs get picked.

You are asked to calculate $|A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap A_3^c\cap A_4^c\cap A_5^c|$, i.e. the number of ways of picking four people such that no husband-wife pair is picked.  From this you can calculate the probability by dividing by the number of ways that you can choose four people ignoring the condition on married couples.

At this point you should apply [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

$|A_1^c\cap\dots\cap A_5^c|=|U|-|A_1|-|A_2|-\dots+|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+\dots-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|-\dots+\dots$

Now, note that the intersection of three or more events is empty and there is a great deal of symmetry involved.  How large is $|A_1|$?  How large is $|A_1\cap A_2|$?

$|A_1|$ is the number of ways that the first husband-wife pair is picked.  To count this, the only missing information is who the other two people are and there are $\binom{8}{2}=28$ number of ways to do this.  Similarly, $|A_1|=|A_2|=\dots=|A_5|=28$

$|A_1\cap A_2|$ is the number of ways that the first husband-wife pair is picked at the same time as the second husband-wife pair.  There is only one way of this happening.  Similarly $|A_i\cap A_j|=1$ for each $i\neq j$.

We have then $|A_1^c\cap\dots\cap A_5^c|=210-28\cdot 5+1\cdot 10 = 80$.

The probability is then $\frac{80}{210}=\frac{8}{21}$

Comment: Based on the conversations I have had with the OP in the comments, I doubt he or she has the mathematical foundation to understand your hint at this point in his or her mathematical development.  That said, it is a good hint.   I also want to take this opportunity to tell you that I have learned a lot from reading your carefully written answers on this site, including where I have made mistakes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the compliment.  I learn a great deal each time I read others' answers as well including yours.  Arguably, your solution for this problem was cleaner and it was out of habit that I went the route I did.  Since the answer has been given, I'll go ahead and finish writing the solution since it is still a valuable tool for the OP to learn for tackling similar problems in the future.  Props for taking the time to carry the conversation with the OP.

Comment: JMoravitz, thanks! And I will try to read more about set theory to understand your help.  Many thanks!!